# Segmentation fault in dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

I am writing a c++ program to code for dijkstra's algorithm. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class vertex;
class node
{
public:
int value;
//bool exp=false;
char c;
};
class edge
{
public:
    vertex* head;
    vertex* tail;
    int length;
    edge(vertex*h,vertex* t, int l)
    {
        head=h;
        tail=t;
        length=l;
    }
};
class vertex:public node
{
public:
    vector<edge*> a;
    vertex& operator|(vertex &p)
    {
        int l;
        cout<<"Give the length of edge "<<this->c<<p.c<<endl;
        cin>>l;
        edge q(&p,this,l);
        a.push_back(&q);
    }
    vertex(char a)
    {
        c=a;
    }
};
int main()
{
    vertex e('e');
    vertex d('d');
    vertex b('b');
    vertex c('c');
    vertex a('a');
    vertex s('s');
    s.value=1;
    a.value=2;
    b.value=3;
    c.value=4;
    d.value=5;
    e.value=6;
    s|a;
    s|b;
    a|c;
    b|c;    
    b|d;
    c|d;
    c|e;
    d|e;
    cout<<"4";
    map <char ,int >A;
    vector<edge*>::iterator minin;
    vector<edge*>::iterator j;
    int min=0;
    vector<vertex*> X;
    X.push_back(&s);
    A['s']=0;
    vector<vertex*>::iterator i=X.begin();
    for(; i<X.end(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"1";
        j=((*i)->a).begin();
        for(; j<((*i)->a).end(); j++)
        {
            cout<<"2";
            if((*j)->length+A[((*j)->tail)->c]>min)
            {
                cout<<"3";
                minin=j;
                min=(*j)->length+A[((*j)->tail)->c];
            }

        }

    }
    X.push_back((*minin)->head);
    A[((*minin)->tail)->c]=min;
    cout<<((*minin)->head)->value;

}
```

The program returns a segmentation fault. I have used various `cout` statements to check where the fault occured but nothing is printed in console. However, I am able to input the edge length in the console but after giving the input it directly gives segmentation fault.

Comment: You should take the habit of reducing the code as much as possible before posting here, as it helps finding errors. See also the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
a.push_back(&q);
```

you are storing the address of a local object, which will cease to exist once the function terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a class to keep your vertices/nodes?. I think you should use plain integers from 0 to N - 1 to avoid get things more complicated. If vertices are identified by a string or something else, you could use a hash/map data structure to transform the keys to an integer. That will help you to avoid moving complex vertex structures and using pointers.

The Edge class seems fine because the Dijkstra's algorithms needs all that data to work (start, end vertices, and the weight/cost of the path).

Having said that, the algorithm could be implemented using a binary heap data structure to prioritize the edge selection. You could also use a priority queue (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) if you don't want to implement a binary heap.

Finally, I would use a Edge vector to iterate over the adjacent vertices of every vertex.